# Creating a bash script that acts as a fortune teller or "magic 8 ball" essentially

Tags: bash, loops, scripting

I am trying to create a bash script that is essentially like a magic 8 ball with 6 different responses (Yes, No, Maybe, Hard to tell, Unlikely, and Unknown). The key is that once a response is given, it should not be given again until all responses have been given.

Here is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Ask and you shall receive your fortune: "
n=$((RANDOM*6/32767))
while [`grep $n temp | wc awk '{print$3}'` -eq 0]; do
   n=$((RANDOM*6/32767))
done
grep -v $n temp > temp2
mv temp2 temp
```

Basically I have the 6 responses all on different lines in the temp file, and I am trying to construct the loops so that once a response is given, it creates a new file without that response (temp2), then copies it back to temp. Then once the temp file is empty it will continue from the beginning.

I'm quite positive that my current inner loop is wrong, and that I need an outer loop, but I'm fairly new to this and I am stuck.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks h3nr1x for cleaning up the formatting. I had originally submitted the question with the proper formatting, but something caused it to become disorganized.

Comment: Don't worry I'm trying to run your script right now

Comment: Can you please post the `temp` file content? I'm trying to guest the format but, as I can see, it looks like it has 3 columns, right?

Comment: it has the responses each on their own, numbered line, like so:
1 Yes
2 No

Comment: Sorry I didn't realize hitting enter submits a comment, but each response is on its own line, with the line numbered. It is not showing up on its own line in the comments, but if that is not clear I could post a screenshot to show you.

Comment: Ok, I got it, but it prints `wc: {print $3}: No such file or directory`, do you get the same error message?

Comment: don't you want 1 + (RANDOM % 6) ?

Comment: Yes I did as well. I used a similar technique in something completely different that I referenced for this one. What I'm trying to do their is count the number lines in the temp file, I'm assuming from this error that's completely the wrong technique..

Comment: Amir, I do believe that would work. What I have now is something I am referencing from a more simple script that also selected 6 things that I had made in a linux class in the past, and it worked. I will try what you have suggested and compare it to what I have now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

shuffle() {
   local i tmp size max rand

   # $RANDOM % (i+1) is biased because of the limited range of $RANDOM
   # Compensate by using a range which is a multiple of the array size.
   size=${#array[*]}
   max=$(( 32768 / size * size ))

   for ((i=size-1; i>0; i--)); do
      while (( (rand=$RANDOM) >= max )); do :; done
      rand=$(( rand % (i+1) ))
      tmp=${array[i]} array[i]=${array[rand]} array[rand]=$tmp
   done
}

array=( 'Yes' 'No' 'Maybe' 'Hard to tell' 'Unknown' 'Unlikely' )

shuffle
for var in "${array[@]}"
do
  echo -n "Ask a question: "
  read q
  echo "${var}"
done
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Upon running this the output was all 6 of the responses. I am aiming to have the user input a question that will receive one response at a time.

Comment: it works flawlessly. once all 6 responses have been given, the script stops though. is it possible to continue from the beginning with all responses being possible once you have ran through all 6?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a script that follows your initial approach (using temp files):

```
#!/bin/bash

# Make a copy of temp, so you don't have to recreate the file every time you run this script
TEMP_FILE=$(tempfile)
cp temp $TEMP_FILE

# You know this from start, the file contains 6 possible answers, if need to add more in future, change this for the line count of the file
TOTAL_LINES=6

echo "Ask and you shall receive your fortune: "
# Dummy reading of the char, adds a pause to the script and involves the user interaction
read

# Conversely to what you stated, you don't need an extra loop, with one is enough
# just change the condition to count the line number of the TEMP file 
while [ $TOTAL_LINES -gt 0 ]; do
    # You need to add 1 so the answer ranges from 1 to 6 instead of 0 to 5
    N=$((RANDOM*$TOTAL_LINES/32767 + 1))

    # This prints the answer (grab the first N lines with head then remove anything above the Nth line with tail)
    head -n $N < $TEMP_FILE | tail -n 1

    # Get a new file deleting the $N line and store it in a temp2 file
    TEMP_FILE_2=$(tempfile)
    head -n $(( $N - 1 )) < $TEMP_FILE > $TEMP_FILE_2
    tail -n $(( $TOTAL_LINES - $N )) < $TEMP_FILE >> $TEMP_FILE_2
    mv $TEMP_FILE_2 $TEMP_FILE

    echo "Ask and you shall receive your fortune: " 
    read

    # Get the total lines of TEMP (use cut to delete the file name from the wc output, you only need the number)
    TOTAL_LINES=$(wc -l $TEMP_FILE | cut -d" " -f1)
done
```

Comment: You're welcome, added some comments to the code explaining the steps

Comment: It is very close, however once the first letter of a question is typed a response will be printed immediately after the first character with no spaces in between, and then will prompt for another question.

Comment: Ok, is easy, just take out the `-N 1` part from the `read` command, I'll update the answer

Comment: Just updated and reran, the problem still occurs when typing the first question, but not after that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ man shuf

SHUF(1)                                                           User Commands

NAME
       shuf - generate random permutations

SYNOPSIS
       shuf [OPTION]... [FILE]
       shuf -e [OPTION]... [ARG]...
       shuf -i LO-HI [OPTION]...

DESCRIPTION
       Write a random permutation of the input lines to standard output.
```

More stuff follows, you can read it on your own machine :)